# lightning vs classic communities

Tags: community, lightning-experience

I want to know is it mandatory to use lightning org with lightning community or Can we use classic view with lightning community ?

Lightning communities VS Classic communities ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule as what you want to use. Classic and Lighting provide you with different interface and UX (User Experience) and has no co-relation when it comes to which community you can use. You use it depending on your use cases.

Also note that your Salesforce Org (when you login using test.salesforce.com or login.salesforce.com) and a Community hosted on your Org (you login to your community using different url) are hosted on different domains. So there's no restriction as you have to be in Classic in your Salesforce Org to be able to use a Lightning Community and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

I am on latest Winter 19 org and it is letting me create a new community. My org is totally lightning with No visualforce page.

[image]

It still allows me to create VF classic community. Salesforce + VF is officially supported community, not like Kokua or koa which are deprecated. So yes its possible to have a classic community even in latest lightning org.

That being said, there are certain reasons why you should not go that route.

1. VF is Page Centric and Rendered Server side and hence can't provide a rich experience
2. Lightning is evolving quite quickly, richer components are readily available which eases your work of building them on your own
3. People have only worked on lightning in last couple of years, so it would be hard to find resources who wants on 10-year-old VF technology.