# Migrate from existing classic community to lightning community

Tags: community, lightning-community

what are the ways we can use to migrate from classic community to lightning community? Do we have to use a new template and create new community?

Answer (score 2):

The question is too broad to give answer, but below references can help you:-

1. [lightning vs classic communities](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233236/lightning-vs-classic-communities)
2. [Can I convert a community created in VisualForce Pages to Lightning bolt theme?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240813/can-i-convert-a-community-created-in-visualforce-pages-to-lightning-bolt-theme)
3. [migrate classic communities to salesforce Lightning](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000XiRqQAK)
4. [Communities: What’s Different or Not Available in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_gaps_limitations_communities.htm&type=5)
5. [Considerations for Changing Your Community Template](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_template_considerations.htm&type=5)
6. [Change Your Community Template](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_template_change.htm&type=5)

Some Highlights:-

- When you change your template, Salesforce object data carries over,
  but branding and component customizations do not. You will have to
  redo your customizations. You can back up most customizations by
  exporting your community. See Save a Copy of Your Community’s
  Customizations.
- Changing the community template updates the navigation options in
  Community Workspaces or Community Management. To view all available
  navigation options regardless of template selection, select
  Administration | Preferences | Show all settings in Community
  Workspaces or Community Management.
- Your community URL changes when switching from a Salesforce Tabs +
  Visualforce template to any other template type. Specifically, /s is
  appended to the community URL. Be sure to update any links to your
  community with the updated URL.
- Apart from the Help Center template, we don’t recommend changing from one Lightning community template to another. So for example, avoid changing from a Customer Service template to a Partner Central template. Although the functionality is available for these templates, we recommend that you start afresh with a new community instead. If you do change from one Lightning community template to another and lose your customizations, Salesforce Customer Support is unable to assist you.
- In active communities

  - When you switch over to the Koa, Kokua, or Customer Service templates, your template change is saved in a draft version. Use the draft version to further customize your community in Community Builder. Your community is updated only after you publish your changes.
  - When you switch to the Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce template from any other template, your changes immediately reflect in your active community. In this scenario, we recommend that you deactivate your community before you change your template. Once you’ve made all your changes, reactivate the community.
  - If your template is listed as None, it means you’re not using a predefined template or you are using a modified version of one of our templates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  It might be a stupid question but we have to have a new template or is it possible to use existing template and add lightning styling into it.